# jQuery ".done" does not trigger after successful response in a React child component

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, preact

I am using jquery ajax in my preact project similar to reactjs. It work in main component well but when I call similarly from a child component the .done is not trigere even after successful 200 response which I can see in my chrome network tab. The "complete" triggers but not ".done". Here is my code.

```
    credentials = {
        targetgroup: targetgroup,
        type: type,
        zip: zip,
        city: city,
        consumption: consumption
    }
    console.log("Requesting")

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/tvabi/step/one", 
        data:credentials,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    })
    .done(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was due to my back end API. It return data and response but does not drop the connect. I used return statement in my golang API to fix it.